# What is meant by connection.Dispose() in C#?

Tags: c#

What is meant by `connection.Dispose()` in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class implements [IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) contains a method called `Dispose()`, where you can release resources or do something else.

Also, a `using` statement can help to call `Dispose()` method automatically.

```
using (SqlConnection connection  = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
   //do something
}// it will automatically Dispose() here
```

What happens when you call `myClass.Dispose()` depends on what you wrote in the `Dispose` method. For example:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   //since MyClass implements IDisposable, it must contain a Dispose() method otherwise will compile error
   public void Dispose()
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

so if you want to know what happened when you call `connection.Dispose()`, you must take a look at the `Dispose()` method of the class of connection(maybe it's a SqlConnection?). If it's a .NET built-in library(which means you can't get the source code easily), you can use a tool to help called [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Comment: what is actually happening when we call dispose() method?

Comment: Just as an edit,
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...)){} translates to
try{
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(...);
}
finally{
 sqlConnection.Dispose();
}

Comment: @Danny Chen: hi almost i got it..so will it release the memory from RAM.. can you compare with connection.Close()

Comment: @saj - Suppose we are talking about `SqlConnection`: `conn.Close()` will be called in `conn.Dispose()`. The `Close` method just closes the connection, you can re-open it by `Open` method. While if `Dispose` is called, all the resources of the class are released.

Comment: @Danny Chen: hi good answer... can't we re-open after Dispose is called at a particular scope? for example within a method.

Answer (score 9):

Dispose() method permanently removes any resource ((un)managed) from memory for cleanup and the resource no longer exists for any further processing.

Example:-

```
void DataTest()
{
 using(SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(...)) {
  conn1.Open();
  SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("Select * From someTable", conn1);
  using(SqlDataReader myreader = mycommand.ExecuteReader()) {
   if(myreader != null)
    while(myreader.Read())
     Console.WriteLine(myreader.GetValue(0).ToString() + ":" + myreader.GetTypeName(0));

  }
  mycommand.Dispose(); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally Dispose is called to free resources when you are finished using the component.

The Dispose method on a SqlClientConnection object will force the connection to close.

It is a common [pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern) that can be found not just in .Net but Java too.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) should provide all the documentation you need on the correct way to call Dispose

Comment: so will it remove the resources from memory? and what about connection.Close()

Comment: The object will stay in memory until it has been garbage collected

Comment: so according to your answer Dispose is called to free resources when you are finished using the component. what you mean by free resources?

Answer (score 0):

the conn.Dispose() is call the function in unmanage code.

in fact when programming,you needn't to call this function,just call the conn.Close();