# Difference between initiating sql object inside "using" statement and decorating with using statement

Tags: c#, using

I've doubt what is the significant difference by applying the "Using" statement in same code block with different way , it would be good to know practice the best way for me
sameple 1 code block

```
using (SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
                 {
                     SqlConnection.Open();
                     using (var command = new SqlCommand(store_procName, SqlConnection))
                     {
                         command.Parameters.Add(Constants.PARAM_Value, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id;
                         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                         using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                         {
                             adp.Fill(dtValid);
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 return dtValid;
```

sample code block 2

```
using (SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
                 {
                     SqlConnection.Open();
                     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(store_procName, SqlConnection);                     
                     command.Parameters.Add(Constants.PARAM_Value, SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Id;
                     command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                     adp.Fill(dtValid);                       

                 }
                 return dtValid;
```

Comment: This is not `asp.net-mv`c specific or `sql-serve`r specific question. Just c#. Also, please spend an extra 10 seconds before posting to format the code for better readability. :)

Comment: Actually i'm working in MVC framework thought some one may come across such scenario

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715126/what-is-meant-by-connection-dispose-in-c

Comment: @soykan i'm aware of the using statement and its benefits i'm following the first sample code block 1 , suddenly when i saw the sample code block  2 i couldnt differentiate the different how the system will process and which is best one to follow  and practice.

Comment: @Ehsan sajjad i'm aware of the using statement i was trying to ask the difference between two code blocks alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement is syntactical sugar to release resources (eg memory or handles) without having to write the code for that yourself. So a code snippet like

```
using (var adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    adp.Fill(dtValid);
}
```

is converted into something *like*:

```
SqlAdapter adp = null;
try
{
    adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adp.Fill(dtValid);
}
finally
{
    if (adp != null) adp.Dispose();
    // or rather (adp as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
}
```

(this is just an example to give you the idea, not necessarily the exact code generated by the compiler).

So if you ommit the inner `using` statements in your code, the `Dispose()` methods of the instances will not be called at this point. Eventually the garbage collection will clean up those objects (which normally leads to calls to `Dispose()`).

The difference is relevant if you have a lot of calls to this method and read a lot of data so that the `SqlCommand` and the `SqlDataAdapter` will consume a lot of resources. If you want to release these resources as soon as possible, you should include the code in `using` statements.

You are asking for the *best practice* (which is often a matter of taste). In most cases the first snippet (with all the `using` statements) is preferable, because it releases all resources that are no longer needed immediatly.